# Typescript + React: Typing API responses in a unidirectional way

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently migrating a React app from Javascript to Typescript. I am new to TS so I'm wondering if there are any glaring holes with the way I'm trying to set up the types.

This is currently how my app flows:

[image]

I am thinking of typing all 3 layers of the data that gets passed down from the API to hooks to my component. Below is a simplified version of what I'm thinking. The actual data has 20+ fields.

API layer:

```
export interface FetchTransactionsResponse {
  transactions: {
    id: string;
    reimbursement: {
      amount: number;
    };
    status: string;
  }[];
  count: number;
}

export function fetchTransactions(params: { foo: string; }) {
  return axios.get<FetchTransactionsResponse>('/api/v1/transactions', {
    params,
  });
}
```

Hook, which depends on the API response type

```
import * as TransactionApi from 'apis/transaction';

export type Transaction =
  TransactionApi.FetchTransactionsResponse['transactions'][0];


const useQueryTransactions = ({ ... })
export default useQueryTransactions;
```

Components, which depends on the hook type

```
import { Transaction } from 'hooks/useQueryTransactions';

export interface Claim {
  id: Transaction['id'];
  // notice I don't need the reimbursement or status here, so I don't include it in this type
}
```

Here is my logic:

Why couple them?

- If something in the API response changes (e.g. we removed a field from the response), everything below it (hooks, components) that depends on that field should break

Why do we need to create a type in the components folder?

- There's a difference between what fields are available and what fields we actually use
- If we don’t create a subset, then we have the overhead of setting up a ton of fields even though we only care about a few. This bloats the tests and the code.
- Makes it clear to jump into a specific page and see what the main types / fields are used in that page by storing it in src/components/[Page Name]/types.ts. Every page will have its own defined `types.ts` file

Is referring to the types and their nested types using `Transaction["something"]` acceptable? Does my flow feel ok?

Comment: since `transactions` is an array, it's basically the object that can exist in the array. A "better" way of typing this is `['transactions'][number]` though. Regarding how you have typed your code @bigpotato, I think it looks good. I would perhaps use `transactions: Array<{}>` instead of `transactions: {}[]` for readablity.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `Why couple them?`. Is `Why do we need to create a type in the components folder?` your idea of decoupling in that case?

Comment: @SoGoddamnUgly I am explaining my reasoning behind the architecture.

Comment: @AndréKrosby great thanks for your input!